# Qt Location: MapViewer example: what is locationData?

Tags: qt, qtlocation

[Example's article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-mapviewer-example.html#finding-an-address-geocoding) refers to `locationData` inside of `MapCircle` element. I was not able to find anything about what it really is. It's not defined in the example also.
What is it? Is there some docs/etc. regarding this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the **role** with which [GeocodeModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-geocodemodel.html) exposes the data.